# Saving a large json that comes from the results of a GET request in MongoDB in python

Tags: mongodb, api, rest

I'm trying to have access to the number of concerts( in this example, the "results" array) using  `https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=collections` .

after running the following script on python :

```
import requests

class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
response = requests.get('https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=collections', auth=BearerAuth('myTokenWhichIsHiddenHere'))

print("response: ...",response.json())
```

and the output is :

```
{
  "count":5000,
  "overflow": true,
  "previous": null,
  "next": "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/endpoint/?offset=10&limit=10",
  "results": [
    {
        // record 1
    },
    {
        // record 2
    }

    // more records

  ]
}
```

As you can see , there's supposed to be 5000 records inside the results array, however, understandably, my python terminal does not show all of these 5000 (maybe sth around 50 records).

I wonder how I can have access to the records at the end of this large spectrum, such as the 1000th record which will never be accessible with the python terminal on my PC.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use json library and function loads.

```
import requests
import json
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
response = requests.get('https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=collections', auth=BearerAuth('myTokenWhichIsHiddenHere'))

y = json.loads(response.json())
# y is python dictionary so you can just access any item with y[key]
```